# SSRS Show data in horizontal layout

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I new to SSRS, need to develop SSRS report to show data in horizontal layout inline as shown below is pix and data, Please guide with your help:

[image]

```
ID      Type        ID
1   Drawings    True
2   Shop Drawing    False
3   Samples False
4   Specification   True
5   Diskettes   False
6   CD Disc False
7   Bulletin    False
8   Site Instruction    False
9   Sketches    True
10  Submittal   False
11  Product Literature  False
12  Other   False
```

Regards

Comment: Are those 12 rows always going to be the same 12 *Types*, i.e. a known dataset and fixed layout based on them?

Comment: Ian, If it was fixed report, then I would have never posted this question :-).... Row can 10-50-100 any...

Comment: OK, few more... Will ID always start at 1, increase by 1 and have no gaps? Will *Type* be returned in any meaningful order by the Dataset? If not, does any sorting need to be applied at the report level?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one approach to consider:

Create a matrix with one Row Group and one Column Group. Remove the row/column header rows and add a new column, so you only have two textboxes in the matrix body:

[image]

Set the Row Group expression to:

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing) / 6)
```

Set the Column Group expression to:

```
=(RowNumber(Nothing) - 1) Mod 6
```

This creates artificial groupings that will have six values per row.

I set the first textbox expression to:

```
=IIf(Fields!Selected.Value = "True", "X", Nothing)
```

i.e. display `X` when required. The main textbox is just set to the `Type` field.

This gives a matrix of values as required:

[image]

Obviously the formatting is rough but you can see how it works.

If the *ID* value in the dataset is unique and sequential you might be able to use that instead of `RowNumber()`. Also, this just preserves the Dataset order.

Hopefully this gives you a few ideas.