# SSRS - Is there a way to have a table split by a page break to appear on the same page?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, grouping

I am creating a report using MS Report Builder 3.0. For this report, I have a stored procedure built that filters down to the specific rows needed, and then I use a row group to group on a particular field (pass_no). The table that is displayed is 2 columns and 3 rows within the row group. The basic description of what I want to accomplish is instead of the rows running onto the next page, I want the rows to continue on the same page in a new set of 2 columns. Think of it like a newspaper where the text continues in a new column rather than running down onto the next page.

For the example I'm going to use here, there are 12 rows of data returned by the SP, and 8 unique values in the pass_no column which is what my row group is grouped on. So in the report I end up with 8 groups of 3 rows. I'm aiming to have the table display 6 pass_no values (so 6 groups of 3 rows) before, for lack of better terminology, starting a new table.

My first approach at this has been to create a column group and set the grouping expression to the following:

```
=Floor((RowNumber(Nothing) - 1) / 6)
```

While this works in creating a new set of 2 columns, the split for the new columns is based on the row number from the raw data returned by the SP rather than the number of rows sets created by the row group. So because there are 12 rows returned, and the 6th and 7th rows have the same pass_no value, the second set of columns duplicates that 1 set of data. Also, the top 6 rows of the second column set are blank with the second set of values appearing below the first set.

[image]

If I add an additional column group where it is also grouping by pass_no, then I don't get the duplicate values, but I do get a pair of columns for each pass_no as well (as would be expected). I've tried modifying the expression above a bit and changed `Nothing` to the row group name and have tried the table name, but neither of them have yielded the desired result.

I can't alter the SP to do the grouping there because there are other column values that are not identical and I pull that data into a cell value expression within the table using `Join(LookupSet())`.

I have also considered creating 2 tables and applying a filter to the table so the first table only displays the first 6 results and the second table displays the remaining results, but that also looks at the raw data rather than the groupings and `TOP N` can't be used on pass_no as it's a text value, not an integer. This would also cause problems if I need to go to 3 tables.

So long story short, is there a way to do a table break rather than a page break or to overflow columns onto the same page rather than onto a new page?

Here's the pertinent portions of the Dataset:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5082b/1

```
PASS_NO    MASTERTRAN    TRANS_NO    DESCRIPTION             IS_MOD
7913019000  4931019000  4931019000  General Admission Adult 0
7914019000  4932019000  4932019000  Sea Turtle Hosp Adult   0
7914019000  4932019000  4933019000  2:00 PM SEA TURTLE HOSP 1
7916019000  4934019000  4934019000  Sea Turtle Hosp Child   0
7916019000  4934019000  4935019000  2:00 PM SEA TURTLE HOSP 1
7917019000  4934019000  4934019000  Sea Turtle Hosp Child   0
7917019000  4934019000  4935019000  2:00 PM SEA TURTLE HOSP 1
7918019000  4934019000  4934019000  Sea Turtle Hosp Child   0
7918019000  4934019000  4935019000  2:00 PM SEA TURTLE HOSP 1
7922019000  4936019000  4936019000  General Admission Child 0
7923019000  4936019000  4936019000  General Admission Child 0
7924019000  4936019000  4936019000  General Admission Child 0
```

Comment: A question and a request. If you had 14 `pass_no` groups, would you have 6 + 6 + 2 side-by-side? Also, are you able to supply the Dataset to create your sample above?

Comment: @IanPreston, That would be ideal to end up with 3 columns. I'll edit the question with the Dataset now. Thanks!

Comment: And I know the SQL Fiddle was a little overkill, but SO just doesn't have a good way to publish table data! At least not that I've found without line-wrapping.

Comment: FYI, if you use `code` formatting tables look tolerable... I've edited yours in. But a SQL Fiddle is great! Sorry to be a pain... One last question. For `pass_no` with multiple rows like `7917019000`, how should `trans_no` should be treated? I guess you're using the `LookupSet` to join `description` together.

Comment: Yeah I guess the data I have actually looks fine in code tags here because the rows aren't too long. Thanks for that edit! Trans_no doesn't particularly need to be utilized here, but I wanted to show there was more data to work with. I'm actually going to add 2 more columns to the Dataset that might provide some clarity, but really it's just the `pass_no` and `description` fields that need to be used. The `LookupSet` is indeed joining the `description` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data presents a bit of a problem.

As you've already figured out, typically for this sort of setup you'd set up a row group with an expression like:

```
=(RowNumber(Nothing) - 1) Mod 6
```

And a column group expression like:

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing) / 6)
```

This would create a six row tablix that would grow horizontally as required.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749154/ssrs-show-data-in-horizontal-layout/) SO question for a similar example.

However, you currently have the requirement of also grouping by another column - `pass_no` in your case. Normally you can approximate a group-level row number with an expression like:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!pass_no.Value, CountDistinct, "DataSet1")
```

Unfortunately, when you try to add this into one of the grouping expressions like:

```
=Ceiling(RunningValue(Fields!pass_no.Value, CountDistinct, "DataSet1") / 6)
```

You get the following error:

> A group expression for the tablix 'Tablix1' includes the aggregate
>   function RunningValue. RunningValue cannot be used in group
>   expressions.

Based on all this, my recommendation is to try and get a Dataset that has one row per `pass_no` value and base the tablix on this, with the above row/column grouping expressions, i.e. no need to group on multiple `pass_no` rows. So in your example it would have eight rows. You could then have a separate Dataset with all the individual rows and use a `lookupset` function to concatenate the `description`, etc.

Your other option is to try and get everything on one Dataset only, including the aggregates as required. This might not be possible, but for `description` at least you can leverage any of the various techniques [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) to get a delimited list. Once you have this list you can replace the delimiter with `vbCrLf` to split it back over multiple rows.

All this is a very long-winded way of saying that I don't know if your requirement is possible with your data, but if you look at having at least one Dataset with one row per `pass_no` you should be able to make it work.

Comment: OK, I actually hadn't utilized the row group that way. I was focusing on using the row group to group pass_no and the column group to do the 6 filter. Now that I see how to at least to the mechanics of making the table flow "sideways" instead of onto the next page, I can spend some time modifying the Dataset to give me a better starting place. Thank you for your incredibly speedy help!

Comment: You're welcome! Normally I'm not too keen on answering with "I don't think this is possible", but at least in this case I think it can be explained why, plus at least a workaround can be suggested. Also I badgered you with so many questions it would have been rude not to.